# Why does `asyncio.run()` fail, but `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete()` succeed here?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Here's some example code (there may be some stuff here that's not affecting the problem, but it's fairly stripped down from some actual code):

```
import asyncio
from typing import Optional, Union, Awaitable, Iterable, Generator, Any
from asyncio import create_subprocess_exec, wait, FIRST_COMPLETED, sleep
from subprocess import PIPE
from random import random


class Dir:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def __await__(self):
        return self.arun().__await__()

    async def arun(self) -> 'Dir':
        proc = await create_subprocess_exec(
            'cmd', '/c', 'dir', '/s', stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, cwd=self.path)

        line = b''
        while True:
            b = await proc.stdout.read(1)
            if b == b'':
                return self
            if b == b'\n':
                print(line.decode())
                await sleep(random())
                line = b''
            elif b == b'':
                return self
            else:
                line += b


class Runner:
    async def arun_many(self, aws: Optional[Union[Awaitable, Iterable[Awaitable]]] = None) \
            -> Generator[Any, None, None]:
        while True:
            done, aws = await wait(aws, return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)
            for task in done:
                yield task.result()
            if not aws:
                break


async def main():
    dirs = [Dir('c:\\'), Dir('c:\\'), Dir('c:\\'), Dir('c:\\'), Dir('c:\\')]
    runner = Runner()
    async for t in runner.arun_many(dirs):
        print(f'Complete: {t}')


try:
    asyncio.run(main())
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('clean exit')
```

The program runs 5 directory listings of C:\ in parallel (i.e. some processes that will generate a lot of text) and prints the output with a random delay as it comes in.

If you run this script and interrupt it with a keyboard interrupt (Ctrl+C / Ctrl+Break / ..) it will fail, with several error messages like:

```
Exception ignored in: <function BaseSubprocessTransport.__del__ at 0x000002904837EB80>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\dev\bin\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_subprocess.py", line 125, in __del__
    _warn(f"unclosed transport {self!r}", ResourceWarning, source=self)
  File "C:\dev\bin\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_subprocess.py", line 78, in __repr__
    info.append(f'stdout={stdout.pipe}')
  File "C:\dev\bin\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 79, in __repr__
    info.append(f'fd={self._sock.fileno()}')
  File "C:\dev\bin\Python39\lib\asyncio\windows_utils.py", line 102, in fileno
    raise ValueError("I/O operation on closed pipe")
ValueError: I/O operation on closed pipe
```

And:

```
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x00000290483A03A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\dev\bin\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\dev\bin\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\dev\bin\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\dev\bin\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

However, if you change `asyncio.run(main())` and replace it with `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())`, it stops without problems and completes as expected.

I've found that removing the `await sleep(random())` causes a different error instead:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-2' coro=<_wrap_awaitable() done, defined at C:\dev\bin\Python39\lib\asyncio\tasks.py:684> exception=KeyboardInterrupt()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Test\test.py", line 53, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "C:\dev\bin\Python39\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\dev\bin\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 629, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "C:\dev\bin\Python39\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 316, in run_forever
    super().run_forever()
  File "C:\dev\bin\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 596, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "C:\dev\bin\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1890, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "C:\dev\bin\Python39\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "C:\dev\bin\Python39\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 691, in _wrap_awaitable
    return (yield from awaitable.__await__())
  File "F:\Test\test.py", line 25, in arun
    print(line.decode())
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Which I'm assuming is because now nothing really is awaited in `arun` anymore, so I left that in to get the error I wanted to ask about.

My question: why does replacing `asyncio.run(main())` with `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())` prevent the exceptions from occurring. And what would be the correct way to clean up after a keyboard interrupt in a case like this, so `asyncio.run(main())` could be used.

I'm OK with a solution that just works, but I'm not happy with not understanding why it works.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your program works just fine, it's just that you're not satisfied with error output on `Control+C`. I'm not sure asyncio is designed for a clean shutdown when `Control+C` is pressed, there is even a [longish article](https://vorpus.org/blog/control-c-handling-in-python-and-trio/) about that by the author of trio (a competitor to asyncio). If I were you, I would not worry about the quality of output on `Control+C`, or I would create a signal hook that just took the whole process down on interrupt, without attempting cleanup.

Comment: Well, there's little I can do to catch a break (haha), but catching `KeyBoardInterrupt` does the trick - cleanup also works when using `run_until_complete`, so my question is simply "why does that work, but why doesn't it when I use `run`?" (in this type of setup)  I don't mind using `run_until_complete`, but I don't like using solutions that work without understanding potential side effects.

Comment: My point is that it works not because `run_until_complete` is designed to cover that case, but by accident (and might change in a subsequent release). If I had to guess, I'd say the reason is that `asyncio.run` attempts to do proper cleanup, which `run_until_complete` doesn't. This cleanup depends on invariants broken by ctrl-C, which results in errors.